# Non-diffeomorphic surface bundles over homeomorphic 4-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology

For a smooth manifold $M$ an $M$-surface is the total space of a smooth surface bundle over $M$.

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two homeomorphic closed simply-connected smooth 4-manifolds. Can there be an $M_1$-surface that is not diffeomorphic to any $M_2$-surface?